# error compiling pluginlib on a mac?

Tags: ros, boost, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

attempting to install either gscam or usb_cam results in errors involving boost:

Any advice?

> bash-3.2$ rosmake gscam
>
> (after some success...:)
>
> [ rosmake ] All 24 linesluginlib: 3.0
> sec ] [ roscpp: 0.7 sec ]
> [ 2 Active 19/33 Complete ]
> {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------   mkdir -p bin   cd build && cmake -Wdev
> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
> [rosbuild] Building package pluginlib
> [rosbuild] Including
> /Users/rieffelj/ros/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
> [rosbuild] Including
> /Users/rieffelj/ros/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
> [rosbuild] Including
> /Users/rieffelj/ros/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
> -- Configuring done   -- Generating done   CMake Warning: The variable,
> 'CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE', specified
> manually, was not used during the
> generation.   -- Build files have been
> written to:
> /Users/rieffelj/ros/common/pluginlib/build
> cd build && make -l8   [  0%] Built
> target rospack_genmsg_libexe   [  0%]
> Built target rosbuild_precompile   [
> 3%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/boost_fs_wrapper.dir/src/boost_fs_wrapper.o   /Users/rieffelj/ros/common/pluginlib/src/boost_fs_wrapper.cpp:
> In function 'std::string
> pluginlib::getPackageFromLibraryPath(const
> std::string&)':
> /Users/rieffelj/ros/common/pluginlib/src/boost_fs_wrapper.cpp:58:
> error: conversion from
> 'boost::filesystem3::path' to
> non-scalar type
> 'std::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits,
> std::allocator >' requested
> /opt/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:
> At global scope:
> /opt/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214:
> warning:
> 'boost::system::posix_category'
> defined but not used
> /opt/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215:
> warning: 'boost::system::errno_ecat'
> defined but not used
> /opt/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216:
> warning: 'boost::system::native_ecat'
> defined but not used   make[3]: ***
> [CMakeFiles/boost_fs_wrapper.dir/src/boost_fs_wrapper.o]
> Error 1   make[2]: ***
> [CMakeFiles/boost_fs_wrapper.dir/all]
> Error 2   make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------} [ rosmake ] Output from build of
> package pluginlib written to: [
> rosmake ]
> /Users/rieffelj/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110415-221135/pluginlib/build_output.log
> [rosmake-7] Finished <<< pluginlib
> [FAIL] [ 2.98 seconds ]
> [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in
> package pluginlib.  [ rosmake ]
> Waiting for other threads to complete.
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp [PASS]
> [ 4.73 seconds ]
> [ rosmake ] Results:
> [ rosmake ] Built 21 packages with 1
> failures.
> [ rosmake ] Summary output to
> directory
> [ rosmake ]
> /Users/rieffelj/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110415-221135

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9745/error-compiling-pluginlib-on-a-mac?/) by [jrieffel](https://answers.ros.org/users/432/jrieffel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2011-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the same issue with Boost version in ticket [#ros-pkg4923](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4923)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0